# how to achieve this in array key and value conversion in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have one array like this.i want to convert my first array to 2nd array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array(
             [East] => 13
            )
[1] => Array
           (
           [North] => 9
           )
)
```

how to change this array to like below array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
        (
         [0] => East
         [1] => 13
        )
[1] => Array
       (
        [0] => North
        [1] => 9
       )
)
```

here East and North is not fixed.It is possible next time here West or south will come.so can not check key is East or not.

Comment: i am sorry it is returning only integer 1.when i print array.

Comment: OK, looks like I misread.... that should be `array_walk($myArray, function(&$value) { $value = array_merge(array_keys($value), array_values($value)); });` - [Demo](https://3v4l.org/jEXIN)

Comment: I am sorry still same result i m getting.integer 1

Comment: Have you looked at the demo that I created.... the code works (if the original array matches the structure that you posted in your question).... you're not trying to display the return value from array_walk() are you? array_walk() returns a Boolean true/false to indicate success... the array itself is "pass by reference"

Comment: what i need to pass in value.I am sorry i am new to php.

Comment: [Look at my demo](https://3v4l.org/jEXIN)..... that shows you exactly how to use it

Comment: yes it is working.thank you i do some testing on this.thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// $multiarray is your original 2-D array

$array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($multiarray); ++$i){
    foreach($multiarray[$i] as $key => $value){
        unset($multiarray[$i]);
        $array[] = $key;
        $array[] = $value;
        $multiarray[$i] = $array;
        unset($array);
    }
}

var_dump($multiarray);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'East' (length=4)
      1 => int 13
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'North' (length=5)
      1 => int 9
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried two-dimensional arrays?

```
 $arr = array
      (
      array("East",13),
      array("North",9)
      );
```

Comment: how to achieve this from my 1st array .